# Returning DataSet as DTO class

Tags: c#, wcf, dataset, dto

I have a method in WCF service which is returning DataSet to the client. Now I want to convert that DataSet into DTO and return as DTO to the cleint.
Can anyone suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data-table contains `Id` and `Name` columns and your DTO class is something like the following:

```
public class DTOClass
{
 public string Id {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

You could do something like this to convert data-table to corresponding list of DTO objects.

```
IList<DTOClass> items = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(row => 
new DTOClass
    {
        Id = row.Field<string>("Id"),
        Name = row.Field<string>("Name")
    }).ToList();
```